# Calculate average of two sums from two column and show it in next column in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I'm using Jqgrid with summery row at grouping level! Now I want to know one thing, that Is it possible to show average calculated from two summery of different column ? Because Sum is calculating by JQGrid functionality. That's why I'm not sure is it possible or not! Here I've attached my screen shot Please refer that.[image]

In this the sum of forecast and revenue are is showing correctly. I Need to show the average of revenuesum/forecastsum*100 in the sum row place in Accuracy column.
Is it possible to achieve it through any JavaScript coding or JQGrid functionality also?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be fairly straightforward to do this.

Start by adding in the name in the right location int he colModel, then in your jqGrid setup you can inject a blank column via:

```
        beforeProcessing: function (data, status, xhr) {
            //add a "blank" column that will be built
            for (var x = 0, length = data.rows.length; x < length; x++) {
                data.rows[x].cell.splice(ColumnIndexValueToAddBlank,0, "");
            }//for
        }, //beforeProcessing
```

then in that column setup in the jqGrid (in the right location in the colModel setup)

```
        { name: "CalculatedColumn", .... , formatter: CalculatedFormatFunction
```

The custom formatter function:

```
  function CalculatedFormatFunction(cellval, opts, rowObject, action) {

   return rowObject[ColumnOneIndex] * rowObject[ColumnTwoIndex]; 
  }
```