# Calculate the value of column based on the other columns in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need to calcualte value of a column based on the values of other column . Say I have col A and Col B . As soon as i enter 4 and 5 in these columns respectively. I need a third column which should calculate A * B i.e 20 in Column C.

How to achieve this. Is there any live event supported for this ?

Kindly help.

Regards

Comment: please share your code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution con depend on how you fill the grid (which `datatype` you use).

One possible implementation could be the usage of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). In the way the column C will not contains any input data, but you can use custom formatter to display the calculated value based on the values of two other columns. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746741/315935) for more details.

If you loads the data from the server you can use `beforeProcessing` callback alternatively. The callback will be called *after* receiving the data from the server, but *before* the data will be processed by jqGrid. It allows you to *modify* the data returned from the server. You can for example include additional data for the column C based on the values from the columns A and B. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855764/315935) for the more details.