# Change styling of jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have started using jqgrid for my project and am pretty happy with it.

[Screenshot of data in jqgrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HYq5.png)

I have two small style related questions.

- I am using grouping for columns but the column name with '+' is not displayed properly.'+' is half hidden.How can I rectify this?
- I want to use blue theme. I downloaded the files from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/) and included ui.jqgrid.min.css in my code but that does not seem to work.What could be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, but you should post **in every question the information about the version of jqGrid and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) which you use**. You should include the code (JavaScript and probably HTML) which is related to the problem. It's very helpful if you prepare the demo which demonstrates the problem. You can get for example [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/5w5h2Lgw/1/) as starting point and modify it to youth.

Comment: Hi, I am using free jqGrid.I have tried jquery UI bootstrap and it looks good but do you have idea about how can I make my jqGrid looking like the one in question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15682574/5221939.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the reason of the problems which you described. Free jqGrid with Bootstrap GUI stile without jQuery UI CSS is not yet final, but GitHub contains already version, which it relatively close to release. I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/grouping-bootstrap.htm) which uses `guiStyle: "bootstrap"`. The current restriction of `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` is the usage of `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` additionally.

To customize the color of jqGrid CSS one need just specify border color or background color. For example I used the following CSS rules in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/grouping-bootstrap.htm):

```css
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap {
    border: 1px solid #003380;
}
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {
    background-color: #cce0ff;
}
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-toppager,
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-pager {
    background-color: #e6f0ff;
}
```

The results are like on the picture below:

[image]