# How to change pager background color in JqGrid?

Tags: css, jqgrid, pager

I tried this :
[Change styling of jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268261/change-styling-of-jqgrid)

But it's not working as i'm not using bootstrap version of JqGrid.

I achieved to change the rownum color by doing this in HTML :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .jqgrow .jqgrid-rownum { background-color: transparent; background-image: none; }
</style>
```

But i'm not able to reproduce it for the pager.

I also have search in the file jquery-ui.css as I have changed many colors options to match what i want.
But didn't find any option for the pager either.

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("#your_grid_pager_id").css("background", "red")
```

Comment: Works fine thanks. but the icons for paging are missing ... . Just so I know can you give me some explanation on how it works ? What .css file is implied or referenced to ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use jqueryUI, all the css settings and colors are stored in that css file. jqGrid just uses jquery UI classes for presentation. Refer to jqueryui css file for the colors. More on jquery UI theming you can [find here](https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)